# Script for pulling daily water characteristic data does not save file

Tags: python, download, netcdf

I am a new python user and I need some help. I am trying to download data from [here](https://tds.marine.rutgers.edu/thredds/ncss/grid/roms/doppio/DopAnV3R3-ini2007_da/his/dataset.html) for characteristic zeta, salt, temp, u, and v.

My code is below and is largely modeled from a code used for downloading HYCOM data, which has a data library with a similar structure. This code will run and does not produce any errors, but it doesn't bring any .nc files into my folder... Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong? I know this is really specific and I appreciate any help you can offer.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#automatically download HYCOM data
from pylib import *
close("all")

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
#input
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
StartT,EndT=datenum(2021,6,1),datenum(2021,10,1)
xm=[-100,0]; ym=[0,80]
sdir='.'

#database
url_1='https://tds.marine.rutgers.edu/thredds/roms/doppio/ncss/grid/roms/doppio/'
database=['DopAnV3R3-ini2007_da/his',]

#download hycom data
if not os.path.exists(sdir): os.mkdir(sdir)
for ti in arange(StartT,EndT):
    url='{}/{}?'.format(url_1,database)

    #add variables
    for i in ['zeta','salt','temp','u','v']: url=url+'var={}&'.format(i)

    #add domain
    for i,k in zip(['south','north','west','east'],[*ym,*xm]): url=url+'{}={}&'.format(i,k)

    #horizontal stride and time
    for n in arange(0,24,3):
        fname='{}/hycom_{}_{:02}.nc'.format(sdir,num2date(ti).strftime('%Y_%m_%d'),n)
        furl=url+'horizStride=1&time={}T{:02}%%3A00%3A00Z&timeStride=1&vertCoord=&accept=netcdf4'.format(num2date(ti).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),n)

        #download doppio data
        if os.path.exists(fname): continue
        try:
           urllib.request.urlretrieve(furl,fname)
           print(fname)
        except:
           pass

print('Done-----------')
```

I expect to see .nc files output into my folder location for the time range indicated, but nothing ends up outputting and I don't get any error messages.

Comment: Because you basically never downloaded nor saved as file any content of any url in your code

Comment: I really appreciate your response, could you help me with what to add to save? I basically want to file to save as what I have called fname....

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the URL.
When I look at the Rutgers website you've linked, I find a different URL to request data files.
After correcting the URL, it works for me and files are being saved and downloaded.

The reason why you see no error messages is that the crucial part of the code is within `try`-`except` and the error message is discarded.
This should be avoided.
A better way is to write the `except` statement as follows:

```
except Exception as e:
    print("Error:", e)
```

This way, you will at least have an idea what went wrong.
In my case, it gives `HTTP Error 500`, indicating that the request was not well-posed.
Using the information on the linked Rutgers website, I attempted to correct the URL and arrived at the following code, which downloads the files as requested:

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

url = "https://tds.marine.rutgers.edu/thredds/ncss/roms/doppio/DopAnV3R3-ini2007_da/his?"

# Add variables of interest to the URL
for var in ["zeta", "salt", "temp", "u", "v"]:
    url += "var={}&".format(var)

url += "disableLLSubset=on&disableProjSubset=on&horizStride=1&vertStride=1&"

date = "2021-06-01"
for n in range(0, 24, 3):
    fname = "out/hycom_{}_{:02}.nc".format(date, n)
    furl = url + "time={}T{:02}%3A00%3A00Z&accept=netcdf4".format(date, n)
    print("Downloading from:", furl)
    print("Saving to:", fname)
    urlretrieve(furl, fname)
```

This is for only a single date, because I don't know this `pylib` module and the `datenum` function, but I believe it will work the same when you add the for-loop over all dates again.
Also, I removed the specified lat/lon range, because the given domain seems to be outside the area covered by the dataset.

Some further suggestions:

- Using `from pylib import *` should be avoided, because it makes it unclear where a name (e.g., a function) comes from.  It is better to only import that is really needed.  In my code, this is only the `urlretrieve` function, and one can easily see from which library this function comes from.
- The `close("all")` does not seem to be useful here.  It is probably there to close previously opened figures, but this code does not produce any figures, so no need to close anything.
- The brackets and the comma in `database=['DopAnV3R3-ini2007_da/his',]` are not needed here, and are presumably part of the problem with the wrong domain.